# Javascript / Passing the right optional argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If have this object : `WebGLCubeRenderTarget`

Its constructor is :

```js
constructor(size?: number, options?: WebGLRenderTargetOptions);
```

Among options I need to specify the encoding :

```js
export interface WebGLRenderTargetOptions {
    wrapS?: Wrapping | undefined;
    wrapT?: Wrapping | undefined;
    encoding?: TextureEncoding | undefined;
```

Encoding is enum :

```js
export enum TextureEncoding {}
export const LinearEncoding: TextureEncoding;
export const sRGBEncoding: TextureEncoding;
```

what should be the right syntax to pass sRGBEncoding ?

This one doesn't work :

```js
const formatted = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(texture.image.height, "sRGBEncoding")
```

Edit : Complete Code

```js
const Background = props => {
    const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, "/03milkyway.jpg")
    const { gl } = useThree();
    const formatted = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(texture.image.height, "sRGBEncoding").fromEquirectangularTexture(gl, texture)
    return (
        <primitive attach='background' object={formatted} />
    )
}
```

Comment: Is this TypeScript?

Comment: it is Javascript with react environment

Comment: share the complete code

Comment: It is not *just* JavaScript. There's something else here.

Comment: WebGLCubeRenderTarget's second param is supposed to be an object, you're passing it a string.  Try `{encoding: "sRGBEncoding"}`

Comment: use --  new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(texture.image.height, {encoding: "sRGBEncoding"})

Comment: (Reading the docs further, it looks like the value for encoding maybe shouldn't be a string either, updated in answer below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGLCubeRenderTarget's second param is [supposed to be an object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLCubeRenderTarget), you're passing it a string.

I believe from the docs that the value for the "encoding" option should also not be a string; see the "Encoding" section [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Textures).

Therefore try this:

```
const formatted = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(
    texture.image.height, 
    {encoding: THREE.sRGBEncoding}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass an object as a second parameter:

```
const formatted = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(texture.image.height, {encoding: "sRGBEncoding"})
```